# Is "he plays the piano" stative or dynamic?

Tags: grammar, verbs, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verbs:

> The same verb may act as stative or dynamic. An English phrase like
>   "he plays the piano" may be either stative or dynamic, according to
>   context.

Could someone elaborate, exactly according to what context can "he plays the piano" be stative, and according to what context can "he plays the piano" be dynamic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"He plays the piano" can be stative, when for example, it is being used to state a fact:

> A: Does he have any hobbies?
>   B: He plays the piano.

Here, "He plays the piano" is stative.

"He plays the piano" can be dynamic, when describing someone actually doing it:

> He rises, goes to the piano, gravely sits down, then, **plays the piano.**

"he plays the piano" in this context, is dynamic.

Comment: Your second sentence has mixed verb tenses. (Maybe "rises", "sits", then "plays"?)